# Prove that $A^TD-C^TB=I$

Tags: matrices

Let A,B,C,D be complex matrices $n \times n$ such that $AB^T,CD^T$ are symmetric and $AD^T-BC^T=I$. Prove that $A^TD-C^TB=I$. Can anyone give me any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Is it intended to use only symetric matrices, not Hermitian?

Comment: yes only symetric matices

Comment: I'm very curious as to the origins of this problem.  Can you provide some insights?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no mistake in how you wrote the various relations? Because I believe I can show that what you are asked to prove cannot hold - and usually the assertion holds.

Comment: I'm sure that there is no mistake.It's a exercise from a competition.

Comment: State what competition it is. If it is an ongoing competition, you are cheating by seeking help here.

Comment: No,it's of year 2003-2004

Comment: Still, please state *what* competition it is.

Comment: admition test for a master degree

Comment: Also Putnam 1986-B6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** The given condition says that
$$
\pmatrix{A&-B\\ -C&D}\pmatrix{D^T&B^T\\ C^T&A^T} = \pmatrix{I&0\\ 0&I}.
$$
Now, note that $XY=I$ implies that $YX=I$ and in turn $X^TY^T=I$.

Comment: Readers should note that the trick user1551 used of bundling operators on $H$ into operators on $H \oplus H$ can be quite handy in general, cf. the slick proof of Putnam's theorem from Fulgede's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede's_theorem, Second Proof of Putnam's Theorem).

Comment: The nicest example of such bundling that I have ever seen is given by [N.S.'s answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/416676/1551) in another thread. The [classical proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362/1551) that $AB$ and $BA$ have identical characteristic polynomials also uses such bundling.