# Prove $A^TD-C^TB=I$

Tags: matrices, transpose

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ be square matrices $n\times n$ over $ \mathbb{R} $ 
.
 Assume that $AB^T$ and $CD^T$ are symmetric ( so $AB^T=A^TB$ and$CD^T=C^TD$ )
 and $AD^T-BC^T=I$ 
 
Prove that:  $A^TD-C^TB=I$

$T$ means transpose

$I$ is identity matrix

I need some advice, maybe there is some trick with trace of an matricx.

Comment: be careful, $(XY)^T=Y^TX^T$

Comment: Isn't this false? Let A, C, and D be identity matrices and B be the zero matrix.

Comment: Also, for that matter, it seems to be answered here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463791/prove-that-atd-ctb-i?rq=1