# Exercise of symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices

How can I solve this exercise?

Suppose that $A,B,C,D$ are $n\times n$ matrices with entries in a field $F$,  satisfying the conditions that $AB^{t}$ and $CD^{t}$  are symmetric and $AD^{t}-BC^{t}=I$.  Here $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, $M^{t}$ is the
transpose of $M$. Prove that $A^{t}D-C^{t}B=I$

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463791/prove-that-atd-ctb-i?rq=1

Comment: Use $(AB)^t = B^tA^t$ and $(A+B)^t=A^t + B^t$ with $I^t=I$ and the result follows by taking transposes on both sides of the expression.